# Basic react rendering test: exists() vs. length

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

In your basic rendering tests of a React component, which approach is more solid?

```js
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);

expect(wrapper.exists()).to.equal(true);
expect(wrapper.find('div').length).to.equal(1);
```

Same thing for testing rendered child components:

```js
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);

expect(wrapper.find(MyChildComponent).exists()).to.equal(true);
expect(wrapper.find(MyChildComponent).length).to.equal(1);
```

I find `exists()` to be much more idiomatic. But I see that most people use the `length` version in their tests. What are the trade-offs, if any ?

Answer (score 3):

`exists()` is just a sugar [wrapper](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/src/ShallowWrapper.js#L1012-L1014) of length.

```
 exists() {
    return this.length > 0;
 }
```

So which one to use is up to you, like you I think `exists()` is more descriptive and prefer to use it.

Comment: The link is dead, long live the new link: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/c62cc4114f97f73283b2c1153c6110e574cdbe81/packages/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js#L1636

Answer (score 1):

Do you even need the first check? wrapper should exist anyway when you are doing a shallow on your component I think.

If you do need it, then I like using `exists()` in your first example more than finding the div of a child. What happens if you change that div to a span later, your test case will unnecessarily fail even though we only care about making the wrapper exist.

For the second example it makes more sense to use `.exists()` when the `MyChildComponent` could be rendered 1 or more times in the future, this depends on what your use case is.

It makes sense to use `.length` of 1 when you only ever want `MyChildComponent` to appear once so that the test fails if another dev comes along and renders it somewhere else in the component.

90% of the time I use `.length` because usually it's more appropriate and less error prone to be exact with the amount of items you want rendering.